# ListView with scrollDirection: axis.Horizontal not dynamic

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this code

```
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        HomeHeader(),
        Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, bottom: 10),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              TitleCard(title: "Popular Coffee Bean"),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
              PopularCoffeeBeans(), //widget Overflowed
              SizedBox(height: 10),
              TitleCard(title: "Implementation"),
              SizedBox(height: 5),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

I want to try auto set height that the column shrinks to fit the children. I dont know whats wrong in my code.

I have try to wrap my first Column with Flexible or Expanded Widget, but thats still not working.
any solve for this?

this is my output

[image]

Comment: looks like the problem is inside the `PopularCoffeeBeans()` and not the Column

Comment: remove this `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve my problem. the problem come, becaue i wraping my horizontal scroll direction using ListView.builder. ListView.builder is bad thing for now to create a horizontal scroll direction, of course if in 1 page there are many scroll pages. ListView.builder only support shrinkWrap by main Axis direction, thats mean shrinkWrap will be fine for vertical scroll Direction, but not good for horizontal scroll Direction.

I try to change that ListView.builder to SingleChildScrollView with simple **For loop** to get index Data. And with SingleChildScrollView, you dont need to set height of parent widget because the height will follow the size of the children who are inside.

```
return SingleChildScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Row(
          children: [
              for(int index = 0; index < data_variable.length; index++)
              Container(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                 child: Container(
                     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
                     child: Center(
                         child: Text(data_variable[index]),
                     ),
                  ),
                ),

           ],
       ),
   ), 
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not in your column but in your PopularCoffeBeans() Widget. In that container, wherever you have defined the height increase it by 26 pixels. And as for the problem of running it in smaller screen size, I guess you are trying to define height using the screen height which is usually not a good practice. It is better to define a fixed width to avoid the override solution.

Answer (score -1):

try giving more height to PopularCoffeeBean card your container seem to be overflowing from card container

Comment: i already try this solution, it resolves, but that not giving best practice. because when i trying run the app in another smartphone with smaller resolution, the widget get overflowed also

Comment: use MediaQuery for best practice you can get device height and width based on that it will resize according to device screensize